# A .net class to hold an image in memory

Tags: .net, wpf, image

Which .net class is designed to hold an image data in memory. For example, I have an application, that displays a list of school events. Each event has an image associated with it.

When I define an event class, which type do I use to hold an actual image, that would get loaded from the disk when the application starts?

Is it BitmapImage?

Since WPF was introduced so many image classes appeared like Freezables, WritableImage control, plain Bitmap and maybe some others, and no book on WPF I looked through exlain where which one of them should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `BitmapImage`, it is an `ImageSource` which you need for the `Image` control in WPF and it has the most functionality.